# Is it possible to make a star like StackOverflow has on the left side of questions using only css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have something similar on my site like the follow/favorite question functionality on StackOverflow.

I am just wondering if it is possible to make a 5-side star with only css, or I need to use an image?

Thanks!

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/

Comment: Or HTML5 Canvas Here are some tutorials http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Shapes - Whats possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560816/css3-shapes-whats-possible)

Comment: Check this out: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-star-spinner/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if it is possible it would involve CSS3 and probably canvas. Since they are supported only by the new versions of the modern browsers (even IE9 support is at question), it is in my opinion best to go with good old images.

You have nothing to lose by using images, and you can be sure that 95% of the browsers will support it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this page! It draws as well stars, but using browser-specific properties, so not standard and not very recommendable.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

The only standard way I can thought is using [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=html5%20canvas&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/&ei=Yfs7T82YPNHsOe3tkeAC&usg=AFQjCNFBDJ3a73zyr3NnKU2d_gF_S8LlGg&cad=rja), but I think it's a lot of pain and a lot easier is using an image, and it's not only CSS.